# 2 thread call the same function at the same time

Tags: c++, deadlock

```
void process(int a)
{
switch(a){
case 1 :
    printf("thread1");
    x=1;
    break;
case 2 :
    printf("thread2");
    y=1;
    break
}
}
void Thread1(void)
{
   process(1);
}
void Thread2(void)
{
   process(2);
}
```

Question 1: What happens when two threads call the same function?
question 2 : what about above code ?

Comment: Are you using C?  If so, then please add that tag to your question.

Comment: The execution order is undefined.. both also write to printf that modifies *shared state* (ie. potential for 'bad thread stuff'), but there are answers to *that* question specifically (ie. "is printf thread-safe?"). Also, there is *no* ['deadlock'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) because nothing is .. locked/blocking. The web provide a place to try some basic queries :}